# How do I add this to this string query?

Tags: sql

How do I add the same `select * from database2.western` thing but with where name='" and merged with this code (in the same query)

```
string Query = "select * from database2.western where id='" + comboBox1.Text + "'  ;";
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have two boolean conditions in a where clause?

Comment: Bad idea to put user input directly into a SQL query - Think: SQL injection attack

Comment: I don't know exactly, i just want this string Query to do both select * from database2.western where id='" and select * from database2.western where name'" with the comboBox1.Text thing ofcourse.

P.S I really don't care about the SQL injection thing. I just need merged somehow

Comment: Which dbms is this, would have expected it to be database..table or database.schema.table, unless database2 is a linked server???

Comment: It's schema.table, as in my case: database2.western (database2 is the schema and western is the table)

Comment: Database2 is the schema? Oh well that makes sense then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use user input directly in an SQL query - it leaves you open to an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you did really want to, then use:

```
string Query = "select * from database2.western where id='" + comboBox1.Text + "' OR name = '" + comboBox1.Text+ "'  ;";
```

In practice you should, at the very least, escape any quote marks in the user input. However, it's likely that whatever SQL library you are using has some kind of escape method. Assuming it does, and it's called `escape`, you could use:

```
string idOrName = escape(comboBox1.Text);
string Query = "select * from database2.western where id='" +idOrName + "' OR name = '" + idOrName + "'  ;";
```

Or better, if your library supports parameterised queries, something like:

```
string Query = "select * from database2.western where id=? OR name = ?";
DatabaseEngine.runParameterisedQuery(Query, idOrName, idOrName);
```

This is pseudocode - replace `DatabaseEngine.runParameterisedQuery` with something that works for your library.

Comment: I don't have any escape method. And please, stop with the SQL Injections, there's no way people will SQL Inject it since it's for personal use and i'm the only one who has it. Could you possibly include the comboBox1.Text into the string Query fro mthe first code you gave?

Comment: It's right there, just omit the `escape` call or replace `idOrName` with comboBox1.Text. And why don't you stop with the antagonistic replies to people who are helping you write better code for free? It's definitely right to mention SQL injections because the next person who has this problem and finds this answer may not be writing code for personal use only.

Comment: No, if you change to AND it will only work if both the `id` AND the `name` field are both set to the same thing, which is also the contents of `comboBox1.Text`. With OR, only one of the properties has to match.

Comment: Well coudn't get it to work. Adding the other select * breaks the code ( stops the comboBox to change the textBoxes text to the database values )
Thanks for the help tho, and that you tried.

Comment: It's just for personal use, is an excuse not a reason. As soon as you want to query a date, you'll miss parameters quick..

Answer (score 0):

Ah

```
where [name] = somevalue or [name] = ''
```

As suggested though, you are wide open to a sql injection attack, should be using a parameterised query.